# Way around "first defined here" error?

Tags: c++

I need to have two alternate classes with the same name, that I can switch between each other by simply changing which class is included in main.

For example;

Mode_1.h

```
class Draw{
    private:
        // private stuff
    public:
        void Render(int x, char y);
};
```

Mode_2.h

```
class Draw{
    private:
        // private stuff
    public:
        void Render(int x, char y);
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Mode_1.h"

int main(){
    Draw D;

    int x = 2;
    char y = 'x';

    D.Render(x, y);
}
```

Currently I'm having to comment out the .h and .cpp files I'm not using to avoid the "first defined here" error. What I want is that all I have to do to switch between them is change

```
#include "Mode_1.h"
```

to

```
#include "Mode_2.h"
```

Comment: What about naming your classes `Draw1` and `Draw2` accordingly?

Comment: Should that be D.Draw(x,y)

Comment: Is there a Makefile or suchlike we can see?

Comment: Whoops, didn't mean to make constructors. Those were supposed to be normal functions.

Comment: Since you are happy (as you say) to manually exchange the header included in, say, main.cpp, the only remaining issue is to make sure that only one implementation is compiled for the project. With makefiles you could have two different make targets; with a GUI like Eclipse or VS you could have two different projects with partially overlapping source files; or you could use a single project and manually exclude one and include the other file for each build (which seems more error prone to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put them in different namespaces:

```
namespace Mode2
{
  class Draw{
    private:
        // private stuff
    public:
        Draw(int x, char y);
  };
}
```

In main you can then select the namespace you want to use:

```
#include "Mode_1.h"
#include "Mode_2.h"

using namespace Mode2;

int main()
{
    Draw D;

    int x = 2;
    char y = 'x';

    D.Draw(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:

```
#ifdef MODE1
#include "Mode_1.h"
#else
#include "Mode_2.h"
#endif

int main(){
    Draw D;

    int x = 2;
    char y = 'x';

    Draw(x, y);
}
```

And compile this source file with -DMODE1 or none depending on you wish to include Mode_1.h or Mode_2.h